How many unit cubes are needed to 'hide' a unit cube fully in 3D?
Question: What is the smallest number of nonoverlapping unit cubes that can hide a unit cube C - in the sense that every ray emanating from the boundary of C meets the interior or the boundary of one of the others, the 'hiding cubes'? We don't need the hiding cubes to be translates of the 'hidden' central unit.
An attempt given on https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2018/10/ hides a unit cube with 13 other cubes (the word 'screening' is used there for hiding). Not sure if that is the best one can manage.
Note 1: 'Research Problems in Discrete Geometry' by Moser, Brass and Pach mentions hiding a unit sphere with unit spheres.
Note 2: I don't know if the sphere is worst 3d shape for hiding - in the sense that it needs most number of copies of itself to hide itself.

Can we assume that the word "nonoverlapping" here means precisely that the interiors have empty intersection?

There is a related notion, Opaque sets: "a system of curves ... in the plane that blocks all lines of sight ..." "The problem has also been generalized to sets that block ... lines through sets in higher-dimensions. In 3D, the corresponding question asks for a collection of surfaces of minimum total area that blocks all visibility across a solid. However, for some solids, such as a ball, it is not clear whether such a collection exists, or whether instead the area has an infimum that cannot be attained."

yes. non-overlapping and "interiors have empty intersection" seem equivalent to me.

If the boundary (including corners) of one of the hiding cubes is enough, then you can hide a unit cube with 6 others by just gluing a cube to each face of the original cube.
If every ray needs to intersect the interior of a hiding cube, then the 13-cube example given in the link does not work, since rays can squeeze between cubes that share faces.
In 2D, to completely hide a unit square using unit squares, you need more than 5 squares.  I found this configuration of 6 squares that does the job:


Your profile picture seems relevant...

If the boundary of the hiding cubes is enough, you can hide a unit cube with just one cube, viz. itself.

@EmilJeřábek presumably that fails the 'nonoverlapping' requirement...

I understood that to mean nonoverlapping with each other, rather than nonoverlapping with the original cube. But may be your reading is right.

Thanks for pointing out the subtlety about the 'need to intersect the interior' of the surrounding cubes and construction in 2D. One point: Gluing 6 unit cubes on to the faces of the cube being hidden feels inadequate - what I thought was: every point on the surface of the cube being hidden emits light; surrounding cubes are opaque and no light should get thru which might not happen with the 6 surrounding cubes (edges of central cube visible from far as a wireframe) but the construction with 13 cubes given on nandacumar.blogspot.com/2018/10 (suboptimal, perhaps) might work.

Or one can talk about open rays.
